# Overview with latest edited posts and pages

Tags: posts, pages, admin, users

I'm looking for an overview of all the latest user activities.

But I don't want to see comments on this page, just the edits or creations of new posts or pages.

Unfortunately I can't find such a page on our installation. Could you help me out?

Comment: You will have to search for a plugin for such functionality.

Comment: @Borek Thank you for your comment. Do you know of one?

Comment: Yup, but can't give you any specific names cuz' the forum is not a place to post opinions on plugins and/or recomendations for those. That said just type in google: "wordpress user activities plugin" and you will have plenty to choose from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the $WPDB query to query the DB, an example would be:

```
$editedposts = $wpdb->get_results( 
"
 SELECT ID, post_title 
 FROM $wpdb->posts
 WHERE post_modified = between DateAdd(DD,-7,GETDATE() ) and GETDATE()
"
);
```

This lists all posts which have been edited in the last 7 days (not tested), you would do something similar to get posts created in that date:

```
$newposts = $wpdb->get_results( 
"
 SELECT ID, post_title 
 FROM $wpdb->posts
 WHERE post_date = between DateAdd(DD,-7,GETDATE() ) and GETDATE()
"
);
```

You can then query the data using the variable e.g.

```
foreach ( $editedposts as $newposts ) {
 echo $newposts->post_title;
}
```