# WP_Query Limit Data_Query last 90 days

Tags: wp-query

I want to perform a `WP_Query` that finds all posts limited to the last 90 days.  From my understanding, [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) accepts numerical values for months, years, days, etc, but I'm not sure I understand how to pass an argument that says "get all posts from 90 days ago until today."

I'm guessing I have to get the current time and then subtract 90 days from that, but it looks like the "day" argument is relative to the month (i.e. 1-31).  There is no way to compare timestamps?

This is sort of what I have so far -

```
$today = getdate(); 
'date_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'day' => array( $today["day"], $today["day"] - 90 ),
                        'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
                    )
                )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to query posts with a [`date_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters), you can pass the argument of column `post_date_gmt` which is the date the post was published, and then pass the argument of `before/after` and a string to represent your request.  So for published posts from now until 90 days ago, you would put this in your `WP_Query` args:

```
'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
            'after'  => '90 days ago',
        )
)
```

This says get me all posts from 90 days ago and AFTER, which would stop at present time.

You could pass the string `3 months ago`, `1 year ago`, etc.  It basically takes on the same behavior of `strtotime()`.

Comment: sorry, this is updated.

Comment: Perfect, it's so much better now.

Answer (score 0):

Not a WP Query but you can do this via a database query using $WPDB, I wrote a [post here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130374/overview-with-latest-edited-posts-and-pages/130375#130375) on it yesterday.